# Importing graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I just want to import graphs from external sources into python and read corresponding x and y-values.
Is it possible in with any python module and if possible what format can the graphs be imported?

I searched for such modules but could only find articles for plotting graphs

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's not clear what exactly you mean, are you asking for libraries to take data and plot it into a chart, or to take a visual image of an existing chart and use it to calculate the underlying data?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library for loading .csv, .xls, .xlsx and some other files with it.

you can install it using `pip install pandas`, this is the example for loading files:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df.head()
```

for loading csv file into python list you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
x_list = df["x"].tolist() # reading the column named "x" and convert it to list
y_list = df["y"].tolist() # reading the column named "y" and convert it to list
```

and for loading them into [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
x_list = df["x"].to_numpy() # reading the column named "x" and convert it to numpy array
y_list = df["y"].to_numpy() # reading the column named "y" and convert it to numpy array
```